# How to call nested function in javascript

Tags: javascript

I copy some code from Online which has the below format code.

```
( function() {
    function finder(){ 
       var findval = {
           find : function(){
              console.log("call this Function");
           }
       };
    }
});
```

I want to Print `call this Function`

I try like this

```
finder.findval.find();
```

When I am calling this the Following Error Will occure.

```
 VM205:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: finder is not defined
         at <anonymous>:1:1
```

**CODE UPDATE:**

I create a variable Outside Which is Not Working always.

```
var outside_call;
( function() {
 function finder(){ 
   var findval = {
       find : function(){
          console.log("call this Function");
       }
   };
 }
 outsidecall = function(){ 
    //how to call from this place ?
 }
});
```

But it is not working.How can I do this.Anyone please help me.

Comment: You'd need to assign it to a variable outside of the scope of your first anonymous function.

Comment: Remove the first and last line of your code, and replace`var findval` with `this.findval`.

Comment: You're creating inner function, which is only visible for the inner scope...

Comment: From that code you cant get `finder.findval.find();` to work. `findval` is not a property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer following code snippet. You need to return findval object at all;

```
( function() {
 function finder(){ 
   var findval = {
       find : function(){
          console.log("call this Function");
       }

   };
   return findval;
 }

 outsidecall = function(){ 
    var findval = finder();
    findval.find();
 }

 outsidecall();
})();
```

Comment: Thank you bro,That's Working Fine for me :)

Comment: IT WORKS FOR ME

Answer (score -1):

how about?

```
var finder = {
    findval: {
        find(){
            console.log("call this Function");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Some explanation would be helpful here.